# Remove Toolbar from QGIS Toolbars Menu

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgis, pyqgis

I'd like to know how to fully remove a toolbar in PyQGIS, so that the toolbar is not only no longer visible in the toolbar area, but also no longer listed under the View menu (View > Toolbars) or when right-clicking on the toolbar area.

It is easy enough to remove a toolbar from the main window toolbar area using `iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar(toolbar)`. This will also remove it from the listing that is shown when right-clicking on the toolbar area. However, it will not remove the toolbar from the View/Toolbar menu.

```py
toolbar = QToolBar('Test Toolbar')
# Add to main window & to 'View' menu
iface.addToolBar(toolbar)
# Remove from main window
iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar(toolbar)
# 'Test toolbar' is still visible in 'View' menu
```

How can I make it so that the toolbar is no longer accessible from the UI?

Comment: Dose `iface.mainWindow()` have a hide function or something like that? could you add the source of qGIS that you are working with in question?

Comment: I am running QGIS 3.20.3 on Mac OS 11.2.3, but I would like to have cross-platform support, over as many versions as possible (ideally any QGIS > 3.0, but as long as it works with the latest version I will be happy).

Comment: `iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar()` is apparently the natural compliment of `iface.mainWindow().addToolBar()`; there is also `iface.addToolBar()` which not only adds the toolbar to the window, but also registers it in the toolbar menu. Sadly there does not seem to be any `iface.removeToolBar()`. I guess there is some way to access the menu item & delete it, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) on the toolbar object schedules it for deletion and completely removes it also from the `view -> toolbars` menu. Note that you won't be able to further use the toolbar after that, for example re-adding it with `iface.addToolBar(toolbar)` will not work.

```py
toolbar = QToolBar('Test Toolbar')
# Add to main window & to 'View' menu
iface.addToolBar(toolbar)
# Remove from main window & 'View' menu
toolbar.deleteLater()
```